# Calling a function that returns a hash value: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, hash, encode, sha256

I have the following code (mid development) and have run into an error. As far as I can see I am passing a text to the SHA256 function but it suggests it is a tuple.

```
from hashlib import sha256
MAX_NONCE=10000

def SHA256(text):
  return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest() #returns a hash value
  
def mine(blockno,transactions,previous_hash,prefix):
  nonce=1
  
  text=str(blockno)+transactions+previous_hash+str(nonce)
  new_hash=SHA256(text)
  print(new_hash)



#STARTING POINT OF THE PROGRAM

transaction =""" 
STUFF HERE

   """
difficulty=3
newhash = mine(7,transaction,"F823482798723897293874982734982F",difficulty)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    newhash = mine(7,transaction,"F823482798723897293874982734982F",difficulty)
  File "main.py", line 11, in mine
    new_hash=SHA256(text)
  File "main.py", line 5, in SHA256
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest() #returns a hash value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

repl.it
https://replit.com/@teachyourselfpython/WiltedLawngreenInvocation#main.py

Comment: Is `text=str(blockno)+transactions,previous_hash+str(nonce)` a typo? Seems to be with the middle `,` meant to be `+`

Comment: yes, see update :)

Comment: If it is simply a typo, you could delete the question. If you have a completely different error now, maybe ask a different question rather than mutating this question beyond recognition.

Comment: I ran your code with the fixed typo, and it runs fine. I think the question is worth deleting.

Comment: updated quetsion to just reflect this current error

Comment: I just ran it now and it doesn't work - same error

Comment: https://replit.com/@teachyourselfpython/WiltedLawngreenInvocation#main.py

Comment: Then maybe it's a versions or package issue. On my PyCharm it runs perfectly.

Comment: Well, it is then still a valid question. It is suggesting tuple rather than text. What is the error suggesting

Comment: I copied and pasted the code and it also works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what argument you feed into SHA256(text).

text needs to be a string in order for encode() to work.

You could try handling tuples also.

```
def SHA256(text):
    if type(text) == str:
        return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest() #returns a hash value
    else:
        list_of_hashes = []
        for each in text:
            list_of_hashes.append(sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest())
        return list_of_hashes
```

Comment: can you please explain why text isn't text? As far as I can see it is.

Comment: for instnace, this is the exact same thing (generation of text) and it works fine without the tuple error. https://replit.com/@teachyourselfpython/BitcoinSHA256withoutcomments

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. I am still getting the tuple error and no one has explained it. Is SHA256 only taking text, and isn't text (the variable) text!

Comment: Your error changed to: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3'

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: After you edited the question, the error is not a tuple error anymore

Comment: Thanks @Ben Alan - not your fault that happened, appreciate the answer and explanation